# Error reading a file and updating a label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, io, streamreader

Here is the code I am working with:

```
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\scan.cmd";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
// Read the file and display it line by line.
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("\\log.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    itemBeiingScanned_Label.Content = line;
}

file.Close();
```

When building it runs everything up until this point and then throws two identically worded unhanded exception's:

Exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SpywareKing.MainWindow' >that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Any insight would be appreciated-- I can provide more information if there is something that you need to help with looking into the root of the problem.

Here is some potentially useful information from the debug console in Visual Studio:

> 'SpywareKing.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpywareKing.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SpywareKing.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
>
> The thread 0x33dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SpywareKing.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
>
> The program '[13492] SpywareKing.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Paste your XAML. The problem is not in your code you have shown.

Comment: Check inner exception for actual error.

Comment: What do you think this means: `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the line

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("\\log.txt");
```

is the cause of the error. You cannot safely assume that the current directory is the one where the log file resides. Always specify the full path.

```
string logFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log.txt")
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(logFie);
```

The current directory can change at any time when the user is selecting a directory in a FileOpenDialog or FileSaveDialog. It's not automatically the applications directory. Also the applications directory will be `\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug` when debugging. Is this the directory you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to tweak this just a little bit to:

    string logFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\log.txt";

            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new      

    System.IO.StreamReader(logFile);

Comment: `Path.Combine()` has the advantage to automatically fix (add or remove) backslashes (\\) where needed.